# How can i mention shutdown behaviour on instance by aws command line interface commands. please assists

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, command-line-interface

Here is my aws cli command for launching ec2 instance, these cli command working succesfully.

```
    aws ec2 run-instance --region ap-south-1 \
    --count 1 \
    --image-id myamiid \
    --security-group-ids mysgid \
    --subnet-id mysubnetid \
    --key-name mykeypair \
    --instance-type t2.micro \
    --tag-specification 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Myinstance}]'
```

i need shutdown behaviour command when lauching the instance, please assist to correct the below command on run-instance

```
--instanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior=terminate \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
--instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior=terminate
```